# jquery .click() doesn't display the expected text while button (clicked) and text runs in a for loop. Both button and text is referred by their class

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I'm using a controller (Spring-boot) and injecting the data into JSP page. TextONE and TextTWO are the data injected into JSP page from the controller.

In Jsp I'm running a for loop within which both the button and text (h3) are present. Now when I click any button the TextONE appears which is strange. My requirement is when second button is clicked the TextTWO should appear. Why this happens and how can I achieve that.

Part of Controller code

```
    @GetMapping("")
    public String showHome(Model theModel) {

         List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
         myList.add("Text ONE");
         myList.add("Text TWO");

         theModel.addAttribute("mylist",myList);

         return "home";
   }
```

JSP and Jquery Code

```
<c:forEach var="item" items ="${mylist}"> // mylist here holds TextONE and TextTWO

   <h3 class="text">${item}</h3>
   <button class="click">Click Me</button>

</c:forEach>



<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){


       $(".click").click(function(){


    var result = $(".text").html();
    alert(result + " is the result");

    console.log(result);

   });



 });

</script>
```

On any button click out of two I get the same text which is Text ONE as per the image below

[image: On any button click out of two I get the same text, Text ONE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use unique class name for each button and h3 tag.

In your code $(".text").html() will always return html from first element which using class "text".

Or use below

$(".click").click(function(){

```
var result = $(this).prev().html();
alert(result + " is the result");

console.log(result);
```

});

(this) means the button you clicked. Current object which triggering the event

Comment: thanks for the reply but the problem is both button and text are inside the for loop, hence I cannot change the class name for every instance. Its set automatically. If that was possible then I could have used the Id instead of a class

Comment: Yes use the above code. Using prev() method. It will work for your case.

Comment: Is there a way for me to use .closest() as well in place of .prev()?

Comment: I've been trying this  var result = $(this).closest('.text').html(); but it gives undefined result. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this is,
Send the list count model
like `theModel.addAttribute("size", myList.size());`

Then create an element input to hold the list size
`<input type="hidden" value="{size}" id="count"/>`

Add id to the list elements [text and click]

In your JS code,
Get the list size
`let size = $('#count').value;`

Loop your onClick function

```
for(let i = 0; i < size; i++){
$("#click"+i).click(function(){

    var result = $("#text"+i).html();
    alert(result + " is the result");

    console.log(result);
     }); }
```

Another solution is to lookup for the parent of the list clicked and select its h3 child element

[example here] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-parent-parents-with-examples/

Comment: which is the element which has click id?

Comment: with the for loop, all button elements would have click ids ranging from `click1, click2, click3 etc` when a button, assume `click1` is clicked, the HTML content of `text1` would be obtained. Note you have to use ids instead of classes